# Microsoft Outlook - how to see last used files when attaching a file

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook, filesystems

On Windows 10, I'm using outlook and I'm sending lot of emails with many files. Each time I want to attach a file I'd like the system to show me my last used files. But I cannot find it anywhere, I don't find this special folder or some configuration. My colleague have this but I don't manage. I tried to look in their help manual without success.

So my goal is: After clicking "Attach File" and the dialog window opens - it should show me last used files there.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the last files used in this dialog by clicking on the down-arrow
to the right of "File name".

The list may not be complete, according to the programming of the dialog
by Microsoft.